# Perf top - warning perf not found for kernel

Tags: networking, kernel, iperf

I downloaded perf program for Ubuntu using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic
```

But when I try perf top it gives me this

```
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 4.9.78-xxxx

You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
 linux-tools-4.9.78-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
 linux-cloud-tools-4.9.78-xxxx-std-ipv6-64

You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
 linux-tools-std-ipv6-64
 linux-cloud-tools-std-ipv6-64
```

I tried running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-4.9.78-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
```

But it doesn't work.

I tried

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-std-ipv6-64 linux-cloud-tools-std-ipv6-64
```

But I got

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-std-ipv6-64
E: Unable to locate package linux-cloud-tools-std-ipv6-64
```

Comment: Try `apt install  linux-tools-std-ipv6-64 linux-cloud-tools-std-ipv6-64`, this is version independent and will work for later kernel updates.

Comment: I tried it and got this Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-std-ipv6-64
E: Unable to locate package linux-cloud-tools-std-ipv6-64

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `lsb_release -a` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!
`

Comment: Voting to close as unclear as failing to [edit] your post to respond to requests for additional information is a poor strategy for obtaining quality answers. Not **all** packages are available for **all** releases of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with your particular kernel version which tells me that are either [trying to install software for an unsupported release and should likely upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) or your running a custom kernel. All I can tell you with any certainty is that `perf` is in the tools directory of the [kernel source tree](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools) and that you can obtain the sources for your major version of the kernel [here.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/refs/)

Comment: I tried locally on a 4.4 kernel and perf worked perfectly. But on 4.9.78 this is still an issue. I cannot run more tests on the real machine which has the issue as I could be jeopardizing alot of valuable files which I don't want to loose. But perhaps I can download that kernel on my local machine and give it a try, or if someone from this community has a solution / possibility to do the same, that would be essential. Thank you though for the comment

Comment: @edward If you aren't [backing up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc/586172#586172) you are already jeopardizing valuable files. If you have a tested and true backup and restore procedure, you can try whatever you like. Feel free to drop me a comment when you have accomplished [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012953/perf-top-warning-not-found-for-kernal/1015025?noredirect=1#comment1646646_1012953) and I may be able to add some clarity to my answer.